# select this parrent with a class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="stateF">
    <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''> تهران</a><div class="stateF2">+</div></p>
    <div class="stateH">
        <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''>منطقه ۱ </a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="stateF">
    <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''> کرج</a><div class="stateF2">+</div></p>
    <div class="stateH">
        <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''>منطقه ۲ </a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want show `.stateH` when click in `stateF2` but that `stateH` has 1 parrent of `stateF`

```
$(".stateH").hide();

$(".stateF2").click(function () {
    $("???.stateH").show('fast');
});
```

Comment: First, you cannot have a div i a <p>

Comment: `$(this).closest('.stateF').find('.stateH').show('fast');`

Comment: thank you @ArunPJohny  ! thats work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) methods like following.

```
$(".stateH").hide();

$(".stateF2").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.stateF').find(".stateH").show('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the `stateH` element within the same `stateF` element.

```js
$(".stateF2").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.stateF').find('.stateH').show('fast');
});
```

```css
.stateH {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stateF">
  <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''> تهران</a>
    <span class="stateF2">+</span>
  </p>
  <div class="stateH">
    <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''>منطقه ۱ </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="stateF">
  <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''> کرج</a>
    <span class="stateF2">+</span>
  </p>
  <div class="stateH">
    <p class='itemRightMenu'><a class='black' href=''>منطقه ۲ </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: `div` can't be a child of `p` element, so instead use a `span`. Also it set the initial state use a css rule

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code hope it can work out for you

```
 $(".stateH").hide();


 $(".stateF2").click(function() {

    $(this).parent().next().show('fast');

 });
```

Try this one, it will show the next sibling which in your case is stateH, my bad I missed that, this shall work out

Comment: There's isn't a `next` for .stateF2.